# Displaying inputs in array in alphabetical order - java

Tags: java, arrays

was wondering if someone could write an example code for elements of array being displayed in alphabetical order.
The elements have come from the users input and have been stored in the array.
Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, is it a `String[]`?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please put in a modicum of effort first. For example, search for "Java sort array".

Comment: Call some sort function, there are plenty build in.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: @Mureinik yes it is a string

Comment: @PatrickParker just need an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example

```
String[] strArray = {"Carol", "bob", "Alice"};
Arrays.sort(strArray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

Comment: Note that this Comparator `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` does not take locale into account, and will result in an unsatisfactory ordering for certain locales.